i an having errors while setting up the AppDelegate.mm while upgrading my project to RN 0.74.0
@import Firebase; :- this is giving the following :--Use of '@import' when C++ modules are disabled, consider using -fmodules and -fcxx-modules
self.moduleName = @"BookerTools";  this is giving the following :-- Property 'moduleName' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
self.initialProps = @{};  this is giving the following :-- Property 'initialProps' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'
[FIRApp configure];   this is giving the following :--  Use of undeclared identifier 'FIRApp'
return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];   this is giving the following :--  No visible @interface for 'UIResponder' declares the selector 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
I tried some changes suggested on github , but nothing seems to work and I dont have much idea about IOS dev. new to this.
Below is the my AppDelegate.mm file
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNSplashScreen.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@import Firebase;
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
  self.moduleName = @"BookerTools";
  self.initialProps = @{};
//#ifdef DEBUG
//  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
//#else
//  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
//#endif


  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios"];

 
  [RNSplashScreen show];
  // Define UNUserNotificationCenter
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;
  [FIRApp configure];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self bundleURL];
}
 
- (NSURL *)bundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}


// Required to register for notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}

@end


Are you using Fabric (new architecture)?
